# Ticker hover does not work with hover when content is loaded using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, bxslider

I am using bxslider as live feeds on my website as on a share's website. The content of the feeds is refreshed every 20 seconds from the server.
The requirement was to stop the slider on mouse hover. That was achieved using ticker hover option of bxslider, but that only works on the first load and isn't working after the content is refreshed from the server.

Following is the code for the first load as well as after the content is loaded from the sever.

First load:

```
    var slider  = $('.bxslider2').bxSlider({
    minSlides: 1,
    maxSlides: 5,
    slideWidth: 285,
    moveSlides: 1,
    slideMargin: 20,
    ticker: true,
    speed: 70000,
    tickerHover:true,
    useCSS: false
});
```

On second load the code is:

```
function startRefresh() {
    var timerId = setInterval(function(){ 
        dataService.get_live_feeds( function (res) {

          var currentdate = new Date();
          $('.rates-head .top_feeds').attr('data-original-title','Last Updated : '+currentdate.getHours() + ":"+ currentdate.getMinutes() + ":" + currentdate.getSeconds());

            var obj = '';
            for(var i in res)
            {
                if(i == 'USD' || i == 'EUR' || i == 'GBP' || i == 'AED' || i == 'CNY' || i == 'THB' || i == 'JPY' || i == 'AUD' || i == 'CAD' || i == 'NZD' || i == 'SGD' || i == 'HKD')
                obj +='<li><span>'+i+'</span><span>'+parseFloat(res[i]).toFixed(2)+'</span></li>';
            }
            $('.bxslider2').html(obj);
            slider.destroySlider();
            slider.reloadSlider({
                minSlides: 1,
                maxSlides: 5,
                slideWidth: 285,
                moveSlides: 1,
                slideMargin: 20,
                ticker: true,
                speed: 70000,
                tickerHover:true,
                useCSS: false
            });
        });
    },12000)
}
```

Kindly let me know, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this slider is using jQuery's `.on()` function in a way that it can't bind events on dynamically added elements.
You can create your own hover function using `.on()` with selector argument:

```
$('body').on('mouseover', '.bxslider2', function() {
  $(this).stopAuto();
}).on('mouseout', '.bxslider2', function() {
  $(this).startAuto();
});
```

I'm not 100% sure about `stopAuto()` and `startAuto()` methods. I just had a quick look at bxSlider documentation here: http://bxslider.com/options

You should also replace `body` by your slider's container.